# How can I return a view from Controller Advice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

I have a @ControllerAdvice class and I want to return a single view and
a model with different attributes depending on the exception. This is my Exception Handler method. I want when I catch a MyException the model to have an atrribute status of 404 and when I catch BadRequestException the status attribute to be 400.

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
 reason = "Bad request or unavailable products")
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public ModelAndView handleMyException(HttpServletRequest request, MyException ex) {
    LOG.error("Request: " + request.getRequestURI() + " raised " + ex);

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.addObject("status", 404);
    mav.setViewName("support");
    return mav;
}
```

This doesn't return view "support" with the attributes. My other attempt is by implementing a Custom Error Controller.

```
@Controller
public class MyErrorController implements ErrorController {

 @GetMapping("/error")
 public String error(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex, Model model) {
     System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
     model.addAttribute("status", 404);
     return "errorHandling/support";
 }
}
```

This works but this endpoint is triggered for every exception. I want this endpoint to be triggered when the Exception is MyException.